# Reading mac/linux GUI text as input in a Python script

Tags: python, accessibility, screen-readers

Is there an easy way (probably using some kind of screen reader/accessibility feature) to read UI (selectable) text?

I need to read the text of a single window of a third party program and use it as input in my python script. The text is selectable and both VoiceOver and Orca can read it.
I'd like the text to be parsable line-by-line but it's not essential.

Comment: Does copying the text to the clipboard and reading it within Python (using e.g. [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip)) work for you?

Comment: actually no: I would like the process to be automated

Comment: Do you ahve the control on the external program ? The best would be to directly communicate with it via API, rather than tryhing to use generic UI requests, especially given that it ranges from doable to totally impossible depending on the OS and UI toolkit used.